# Parse: No Session is created when new Facebook user signs up

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions)` for Facebook signup/login in my iPhone app written in Swift.

UPDATE:
When a new user signs up through the standard email sign up, a Session object is created as usual in the Parse Session class. However, when a new user signs up through Facebook sign up for the first time, a Session object is created then immediately deleted in the Parse Session class (after the call to `saveInBackground` - see my comment below). If that new users signs out then logs back in again, finally the Session object is created for some reason. 
**What is the problem here/How can I have a Session object be created when a new Facebook user first signs up?**

I've tried enabling and disabling PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground() in my AppDelegate and in the Parse dashboard app settings but neither would change anything. Note: I have migrated the app to Parse Server.

Comment: I noticed that when I call `newFBuser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock...` in the `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` block, the saving seems to be the reason why the Session object g ets deleted. Note: I need to save the newly created user because I am setting the fetched Facebook user details from the Facebook graph request to the newly created user. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the currently [open issue #2105](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2105#issuecomment-239629076) of Parse Server.

[bryhaw](https://github.com/bryhaw) figured out a workaround:

Log in with the access token that is created after calling `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` like so:
`PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())`.

I would assume that creates a session.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Question: Should `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())` be called inside the `if let user = user` block of `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`?

Comment: `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {`